# how to call onBindViewHolder function for all recyclerview items before scroll down?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

To add the ability to copy an item's data to other items by the user before scrolling down, I need to know the answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

You can't and you **must not** call directly `onBindViewHolder`. 
This can be done implicitly by the adapter itself.  
If you want to copy an item's data to another item just do it in the list you have attached to the adapter and then call `recyclerview.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following OnScrollListener code

```
    RecyclerView.OnScrollListener scrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            // add your copy data logic here
        }
    };
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
```